Concrete Example of an Induced Measure (Difficulty distinguishing between concept of random variable and concept of pdf)
At p. 8 of Mathematical Statistics (2nd Ed., J. Shao), the concept of induced measure is introduced. Specifically, if $\nu$ is a measure on measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ and $f: (\Omega, \mathcal{F}) \to (\Lambda, \mathcal{G})$ is a measurable function, the induced measure by $f$ (denoted $\nu\circ f^{-1}$) is a measure on $\mathcal{G}$ defined as:
$\nu\circ f^{-1} = \nu(f^{-1}(B)),\hspace{0.25em} B \in \mathcal{G}$.
Shao then goes on to state that if $\nu=P$ is a probability measure and $X$ is a random variable, then $P \circ X^{-1}$ is the law or distribution of $X$.  I am having some difficulty with this concept, possibly due to the notation.
I understand that $P \circ X^{-1}$ is likely referring to what I know as the pdf of a random variable, but what I don't understand is why it is expressed in terms of the inverse function of a random variable.  Could someone provide an illustrative example (if one can easily be given) of $P$, $X^{-1}$ and $P \circ X^{-1}$ so that I can understand what the latter term (and its decomposition into its two components) means?
In the spirit of making an attempt before asking, I propose an example that may or may not be a correct: if one considers the sum two independent six-sided die rolls (borrowed from Resnick, p. 75-76), the components of this experiment would be as follows:
(My thanks to Wei for his reference to the "pushforward measure" which assisted me in understanding the theoretical underpinnings of this question - I have edited my question as set out below)

the random variable $X$ represents the sum of two independent die rolls - in this case, the domain of $X$ is $\Omega = \{(1,1), (1, 2), \ldots, (6, 5), (6, 6)\}$ and the codomain of $X$ would be $\Omega' = \{2, 3, \ldots, 11, 12 \}$. So, for example, $X((1, 3)) = X((2, 2)) = 4$, and $X^{-1}(4) = \{(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1)\}$.

the measure $P: \Omega \to [0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ represents the probability measure mapping each individual outcome (i.e. each ordered pair of die rolls) to its probability.  For example, assuming the dice are fair, $P((1,2)) = 1/36$.

in the context of the foregoing, I assume that $P \circ X^{-1}$ directly maps the sums of the die rolls to their probabilities via the individual outcomes that comprise each sum. So, for example, if we want the probability that the sum of die rolls is 4, we do the following:


$P(X=4) = P \circ X^{-1}(4) = P(\{(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1)\}) = \sum\limits_{\omega \in X^{-1}(4)} P(\omega) = 3/36$
Is this correct?  Assuming that it is, why do we not (or can we not) define $P$ so that it maps directly from $\Omega'$ to $[0,1] \subset \mathbb{R}$ instead of doing it via $\Omega$ and having to use $X^{-1}$?
I assume there is some practical challenge that makes it necessary to define a pdf as a composition of $P$ and the inverse of $X$, but cannot determine precisely what it is, if I am even correct about this.

You have a starting probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$, and then $X:\Omega\to{1,\ldots,6}$. Then $P\circ X^{-1}$ is a measure on ${1,\ldots,6}$. Hope that helps.

Also FYI the more common measure-theoretic terminology for this is the "pushforward measure", in case you want to do some further reading.

Thank you, @Wei!

In order to answer your question, it's more helpful to consider a random variable as an "information processor" instead of viewing it as a "random quantity". In this viewpoint, for each "configuration" $\omega$ containing abundant information, the random variable $X$ processes $\omega$ and produces a specific value. Consider these examples:

$\Omega$ represents the configuration of all atoms in the (Newtonian) universe, and $X(\omega)$ processes this information through dynamics to determine whether a tossed coin will land on heads or tails.

$\Omega$ is the set of all pairs $(i, j)$ where $i, j \in {1,\ldots,6}$, modeling the outcome of two dice rolls, and $X(\omega) = \omega_1 + \omega_2$ is a function that evaluates a particular quantity for each possible configuration $\omega$.


This perspective offers several advantages:

It demystifies the concept of a "random variable", revealing that it doesn't inherently involve randomness.

It clarifies why we use $X^{-1}$ when defining the distribution of $X$.
The distribution of $X : (\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbf{P}) \to (\Lambda, \mathcal{G})$ is the probability measure on $\Lambda$ that assesses the likelihood of each possible event related to $X$'s value. Since $X$ produces "processed" values, but you only have the measure $\mathbf{P}$ to assess the likelihood of unprocessed events (let me emphasize again that $X$ itself contains no information about randomness!), you must "reverse" the information processing. This involves converting events about $X$ back to events in $\Omega$, then using $\mathbf{P}$ to assess their likelihood. Consequently, we can express the distribution of $X$ as $\mathbf{P}\circ X^{-1}$.


By the way, it's entirely reasonable to define a distribution on the "value space" $(\Lambda, \mathcal{G})$ as a standalone object, without referencing a specific random variable. After all, a distribution is simply a probability measure on the measurable space of interest. For instance, you can define the binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$ as the probability measure on $\mathbb{R}$ given by:
$$ \text{Bin}(n, p) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k} p^k (1-p)^{n-k} \delta_k, $$
where $\delta_k$ is the unit mass (i.e., Dirac mass) concentrated at $k$. However, when you're given only a random variable and want to examine how the values of $X$ behave, you need to find a distribution associated with $X$. This is where you would apply the formula $\mathbf{P}\circ X^{-1}$.

Thank you for this thoughtful response.  I infer from your (and @Wei 's) answer that "randomness" may simply be our way of stating that we do not have information on a sufficiently-granular level about what is really a deterministic process (your example of the coin flip explained as an infinitely-complex interaction of atoms is particularly apt).  Perhaps what we think is a random coin flip is in fact the deterministic result of an uncountable series of physical micro-(nano?)-events.

Just considering your example, if all you care about is the sum of the two dice, then you could certainly define it as a probability measure directly on $\Omega'$. But in some sense you would lose the information that this random variable arises as the sum of two dice rolls. Using the original setup with $\Omega$, you can define other random variables that allow you to ask and answer any question about the two rolls. What is the probability that they are equal? What is the probability that the first is >5 and the second is <3? What is the distribution of the product of the two?

Thank you again, @Wei, and see my comment above to the other answer - perhaps it is no mistake that information theory holds that information about a process is inversely related to its "entropy".  Both your answers have led me to the conclusion that "randomness" is just a way of saying that a process cannot be described with sufficient (deterministic) granularity. We once used to say it rained because the gods willed it - now we know(?) better.  Thanks again.
